# Return results of a form to search a website

Tags: html, forms, vba, web

I want to submit a form to search this website. 
http://www.hcdistrictclerk.com/edocs/public/search.aspx

My code seems to work for filling in the form. However after, it clicks the search button, the form seems to be cleaned and no result returned.

When I delete that particular line `.all("ctl00$ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ContentPlaceHolder2$ContentPlaceHolder2$btnSearch").Click` and click the search button manually, everything seems to be fine.

```vb
 Sub test()
  Dim searchURL, entity, paintiff, defendent As String
  Dim i, k As Integer
  plaintiff = "ctl00$ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ContentPlaceHolder2$ContentPlaceHolder2$tabSearch$tabCivil$txtPlaintiff"

  k = Sheet1.Range("a65536").End(xlUp).Row

  Set IE = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
  Web_Address = "http://www.hcdistrictclerk.com/edocs/public/search.aspx"

  ' Access the Webpage
  IE.Navigate Web_Address
  IE.Visible = True
  Start:

  ' Wait while IE loading...
  Do While IE.Busy
  Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 5, Now)
  Loop

  For i = 1 To k
  entity = Cells(i, 1)

  With IE.document.forms(0)
  .all(plaintiff).Value = entity
  .Submit

  .all("ctl00$ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ContentPlaceHolder2$ContentPlaceHolder2$btnSearch").Click

  'This line seems to reset the form before submitting for search
  'So it gives me no result
  'If I delete this line and click the search button manually, everything works fine

  End With
  Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: 1) please use code blocks for your code, 2) is this vba or vb.net?

Comment: vba. I am wondering if there is anything wrong with  .all("ctl00$ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ContentPlaceHolder2$ContentPlaceHolder2$btnSearch").Click